# Using DONUT algorithm with keras

Tags: deep-learning, data, anomaly-detection, autoencoder

I am trying to get this repo of Xu's DONUT algorithm running, however I am getting an error I do not quite understand. The readme says I should load raw_data as follows:

```
timestamp, values, labels = ...
# If there is no label, simply use all zeros.
labels = np.zeros_like(values, dtype=np.int32)

# Complete the timestamp, and obtain the missing point indicators.
timestamp, missing, (values, labels) = \
    complete_timestamp(timestamp, (values, labels))
```

however, when I do so, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The shape of ``arrays[0]`` does not agree with the shape of `timestamp` ((109577, 11) vs (109577,))
```

which does not make sense to me as I can't think of a reason timestamp would be an 11 dim array. When I pass the values as the timestamp arg, I get "timestamp must be a 1D array"

Very confused, hopefully, someone can shed some light.

Here are the checks in the code:

```
if len(timestamp.shape) != 1:
    raise ValueError('`timestamp` must be a 1-D array')

has_arrays = arrays is not None
arrays = [np.asarray(array) for array in (arrays or ())]
for i, array in enumerate(arrays):
    if array.shape != timestamp.shape:
        raise ValueError('The shape of ``arrays[{}]`` does not agree with '
                         'the shape of `timestamp` ({} vs {})'.
                         format(i, array.shape, timestamp.shape))
```

As well as the repo itself:
https://github.com/haowen-xu/donut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your `timestamp` look like? Apparently there are too many dimensions.

When using pandas DataFrames you could pass the `.index` (in case it's no multiindex) or just `np.arange(len(<your_data>))` as timestamps.

Comment: (109577,) just a numpy array using df.values. I understand the dimensions are different, I don't understand why the official implementation of the paper wants the timestamp with the same dimensions as the rest of the X data.

Comment: It's more like the data has to be the same dimension (one). As far as I understood, it will not work with multivariate data easily. But you can introduce a simple merging criterion for this. E.g. merging multiple models/predictions by taking the minimum for each timestamp. (or the maximum in case it's binarized already)

Comment: My timestamp is 1d, you mean my values?

Comment: Yes, Donut can only work on univariate data. Hence, it cannot detect multivariate anomalies.

Comment: Gotcha, any idea on the best way to merge 11 dimensions for this algorithm Axi? Or is it best to run it only with single primary features?

Comment: It's probably not the best way but, as mentioned, you can train one model for each dimension and then combine the score by taking the minimum over all. After binarization it's the maximum. Let me know, if you come up with a more sophisticated approach. (If you have the capacities to look at each dimension separately, do so.)